# Height of binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a recursive method to calculate the height of a binary tree. Here is the "height"-code:

```
def height(self):
    if self.root==None:
        return 0
    return max(height(self.root.left), height(self.root.right))+1
```

When I try to call the function, I get the following error msg:

```
NameError: name 'height' is not defined
```

Does anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a method of your class, hence you must call it from an instance (`self`) or the class itself. Though it won't work as you think, unless you define it as a `staticmethod` or change your call, e.g.

```
def height(self):
    return 1 + max(self.left.height() if self.left is not None else 0, 
                   self.right.height() if self.right is not None else 0)
```

or

```
@staticmethod
def height(self):
    return 1 + max(self.height(self.left) if self.left is not None else 0,
                   self.height(self.right) if self.right is not None else 0)
```

Notice, that you shouldn't use `==` to compare with `None` (kudos to timgeb). And you must check whether child-nodes exist, too. And your algorithm doesn't work, so I've changed it slightly.

Example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, root=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def height(self):
        return 1 + max(self.left.height() if self.left is not None else 0, 
                       self.right.height() if self.right is not None else 0)


# Create a binary tree of height 4 using the binary-heap property
tree = [Node() for _ in range(10)]
root = tree[0]

for i in range(len(tree)):
    l_child_idx, r_child_idx = (i + 1) * 2 - 1, (i + 1) * 2
    root_idx = (i + 1) // 2
    if root_idx: 
        tree[i].root = tree[root_idx]
    if l_child_idx < len(tree):
        tree[i].left = tree[l_child_idx]
    if r_child_idx < len(tree):
        tree[i].right = tree[r_child_idx]

print(root.height())  # -> 4
```

Comment: You should also replace `self.root==None` with `self.root is None`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Neither in Python2 nor 3 you'll get an error checking for `None` this way.

Comment: @timgeb Oh, sorry, I thought they made an error out of it in Python 3. I'm using Python 2 most of the time, so sorry for the misconception.

Comment: Now I get the error msg "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'height'". Shouldn't the base case prevent this?

Comment: @EliKorvigo Now I get the error msg "AttributeError: 'Treenode' object has no attribute 'height'". Of course height is a method to the class Bintree which in turn is creating nodes using the class Treenode but surely I shouldn't have to add a height method to Treenode??

Comment: @Lozansky It's only now that I've read your code with due attention. It has algorithmic errors in it. I fixed that and provided an example.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I should add I need to create binary tree as an own class and cannot use it with the binary-heap property. Is there any way I can create a method to Bintree without changing the Treenode class?

Comment: @Lozansky you are not restricted to heaps here. I used the property and the list as an easy way to create a binary tree of specific height. The algorithm itself works for any tree.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I don't understand why you initialize a root in your Node class. Also, should I place the height method in just the Node class or in both the Node and the Binary tree class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108650/discussion-between-eli-korvigo-and-lozansky).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you define your binary tree. But on a tree node you usually have only one root and multiple sons. I have the feeling that this method leads to an infinite loop. self.root.left and self.root.right are exactly my brother and me...

Here you probably have to call the method from the instances self.root.left and self.root.right with no extra argument :

```
def height(self):
    if self.root==None:
        return 0
    return max(self.root.left.height(), self.root.right.height())+1
```